# Ubuntu 9.04 not starting after Installation

Tags: boot, 9.04

I am a quite new user of Ubuntu. I am a Sr. citizen.

My system is a Pentium III, Asus CUSL-2 Mother board 512MB RAM SD

I installed Ubuntu 9.04 on a seperate HD of 20 GB using CHIP's Live DVD to install. It is successfully installed. On starting the system, it also gives booting options. If Win.XP is selected, it starts. But if Ubuntu 9.04 option is given, it starts booting, checks all parameters  and gives [OK] to all but stops at "Checking battery...." it stops and after 2 to 3 flikkers the monitor screen becomes blank/dark... nothing comes on it.

Comment: Try adding paragraphs to the text to make it more readable.

Comment: Navin Sir, pls avoid posting your email id or do [address munging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_munging) if you have to post it in public sites like this. This is to avoid spam.

Comment: 9.04 is a pretty old version. After that we have had 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10 - which is the latest. Any reason you want to stick to that ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is wrong and how can I help, but You should know that support for 9.04 version is until 23 October 2010, so I recommend upgrade of Ubuntu version.